# Force constant of a spring. Vector or scalar?

Tags: homework-and-exercises, newtonian-mechanics

Is the force constant of a spring in Hooke's law a vector quantity or scalar?

Comment: It is a scalar constant for the spring.  And if displacement (stretch) is big enough can be a function of displacement.

Answer (score 2):

It definitely can't be a vector. The only coordinate independent formations that relate two vectors to one is addition:

$$ F_i = ak_i + bx_i $$

or the cross product:

$$ F_i = \epsilon_{ijk}k_jx_k $$

which dont look like Hooke's Law.

The simplest form of Hooke's Law is a scalar relationship:

$$ F_i = kx_i $$

Note that this is coordinate independent relationship, as it is just a scaling between two vectors.

It can also be written in a tensor form as

$$ F_i = k_{ij}x_j $$

with

$$ k_{ij} = \frac 1 3 k\delta_{ij} $$

So the obvious question is can $k_{ij}$ be more than an isotropic tensor? To which the answer is yes, and it is called stiffness tensor. It is still a linear relation between displacement and force, it's just that the two vectors need not be parallel.

The most general form relates the strain (a displacement-like tensor) in continuous media, and the resulting stress:

$$ \sigma_{ij} = c_{ijkl}\epsilon_{ij} $$

where $c_{ijkl}$ is now a fourth rank tensors with 81 cartesian components. Symmetry reduces that to at most 21, but usually much fewer.

Answer (score 1):

I think you mean the spring constant.

$\overrightarrow{F} = - k \overrightarrow{\Delta x}$

In this equation:

$\overrightarrow{F}$ is a vector

$\overrightarrow{\Delta x}$ is a vector

$k$ is scalar